# How to run a function only once, then run another function that relies on the same elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to hack together an infinite scroll system for a site, but am running into problems.

There is basically a div with a whole lot of `<li>` elements.

This function slices the div and hides every `<li>` element after the first 20. Once scrolled to the bottom of the page it shows all and immediately slices to 40 and then hides again the rest again.

```
$("#CategoryContent li").slice(20).hide();    

$(window).scroll(function() {
       if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            $("#CategoryContent li").show();
           $("#CategoryContent li").slice(40).hide();
       }
    });
```

I pretty much want this to happen infinitely until all content is loaded.

Adding the same code with a different slice number obviously doesn't work. So how would I go about that?

Store the value of the first slice in a variable and once the function has been executed increase that variable by 20?

I've searched for plug ins to take care of this for me but they all rely on pagination which currently isn't an option.

Comment: You need to keep an offset value which would be used in `.slice()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this

```
var mincount = 20;
var maxcount = 40;


$(window).scroll(function() 
                    {
                    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 400) {
                            $("#CategoryContent li").slice(mincount,maxcount).fadeIn(800);

mincount = mincount+20;
maxcount = maxcount+20

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's expensive, but you could get the number of visible elements, then add 20 to it. Before calling `$("#CategoryContent li").show()`, you could do this:

```
var visibleItems = $("#CategoryContent li").filter(function( i, el ) {
    return $(el).css("display") !== "none";
});
```

This will return you all items in the $("#CategoryContent li") collection that don't have their CSS `display` property set to `none`.

Then you can just update your slice call to:

```
$("#CategoryContent li").slice(visibleItems.length + 20).hide();
```

That being said, a better way would be to manually track the count and just put a function wrapper around the whole thing.

```
(function ( ) {
    var visibleCount = 20;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
       if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
           visibleCount += 20;
           $("#CategoryContent li").show();
           $("#CategoryContent li").slice(visibleCount).hide();
       }
    });
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do would be to cache your selector. Makes sense, since it looks like you're working with it all the time.

```
var category_content_lis = $('#CategoryContent li');
```

Next, I probably wouldn't bother with `.slice` for this. I'd most probably just use something like the `:lt()` selector to fine-tune my selector somehow.

The idea is to **hide everything** then show them in increments.

```
category_content_lis
    .hide()
    .filter(':lt(20)')
    .show()
    ;
```

Now, if you were just showing them in increments of 20, then you could do something like this to trigger showing the next 20:

```
category_content_lis
    .filter(':hidden:lt(20)')
    .show()
    ;
```

... which can be conveniently encapsulated in a function if you wish. That would work, no matter how long your list is.

Notice that we're not hiding everything **then** showing a selection. Something like that will cause flicker, which is just irritating, and may or may not cause epilepsy.